# ORA-06550: line 1, column 72: PL/SQL: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an error "invalid host/bind variable name" . The Productprice is on the another table called b_product. I want to make calculation , which the price per item is in another table called b_product and I want to display the total price on table ordersdetails. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT :(P9_QUANTITYS) *Productsprice
FROM b_ordersdetails od
JOIN b_product pd ON od.PRODUCTSID=b.PRODUCTSID
WHERE b.PRODUCTSID= :(P9_PRODUCTSID)
```

Comment: I presume that you're using Forms, then you just can retry without brackets for the variables such as `:P9_QUANTITYS` and `:P9_PRODUCTSID`.

Comment: the colon has to go immediate before the placeholder name, without parentheses separating them.

Comment: Hi , thank you for the response but I already change it into                                SELECT : P9_QUANTITYS * Productsprice
FROM b_ordersdetails od
JOIN b_product pd ON od.PRODUCTSID= b.PRODUCTSID
WHERE b.PRODUCTSID= : P9_PRODUCTSID; but I get another error which is ORA-01008: not all variables bound. So what's thats mean? I dont understand

Comment: What are the types of variables (display only, pop-up, number field, select list, ...)? Did you set the source value and how (static, sql, item,...)?

Comment: The type of the value to display the total field is number , and for product id list value same with orders id , both of them are source from share component

Comment: SELECT :P9_QUANTITYS*Productsprice
INTO :P9_TOTALPRICES
FROM b_ordersdetails od
JOIN b_product pd ON od.PRODUCTSID= pd.ProductsID
WHERE pd.ProductsID= :P9_PRODUCTSID;  I get another error when run the applications      **"Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for Execute Server-Side Code."**

Answer (score 0):

try this

SELECT &P9_QUANTITYS * Productsprice
FROM b_ordersdetails od
JOIN b_product pd ON od.PRODUCTSID=b.PRODUCTSID
WHERE b.PRODUCTSID= &P9_PRODUCTSID

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).